# How to sum columns and append the result as a row in the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
|   int_col_1   ||   int_col2   ||   str_col3   ||   float_col4   ||   float_col5   |
|---------------||--------------||--------------||----------------||----------------|
|      123      ||      456     ||     potato   ||     0.1        ||       -0.2     |
|      456      ||      456     ||     potato   ||     0.1        ||        5.0     |
|      456      ||      456     ||     potato   ||     0.1        ||       -0.2     |
|      ...      ||      ...     ||     ...      ||     ...        ||       ...      |
```

I want to sum all `float_col_4` and `float_col5` rows that are above 0 per different `int_col_1` and append the result as a new row.

So the new dataframe would look like this.

```
|   int_col_1   ||   int_col2   ||   str_col3   ||   float_col4   ||   float_col5   |
|---------------||--------------||--------------||----------------||----------------|
|      123      ||      789     ||     potato   ||     0.1        ||       -0.2     |
|      Total    ||     NULL     ||       NULL   ||     0.1        ||        0.0     |
|      456      ||      734     ||     potato   ||     0.1        ||        5.0     |
|      456      ||      423     ||     potato   ||     0.1        ||       -0.2     |
|      Total    ||      NULL    ||       NULL   ||     0.2        ||        5.0     |
|      ...      ||      ...     ||     ...      ||     ...        ||       ...      |
```

How can I do this? I need that to be appended to the same dataframe for simplicity so I guess I will also have to cast the first column from int to str, or drop the "Total" to the `str_col3`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom function in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) for append new rows, for filter values above `0` is used [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) for replace lower values like `0` to `0`, create default index and replace mising values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with dict:

```
#if necessary sorting by first column
df = df.sort_values('int_col_1')


def f(x):
    x.loc[-1] = x[['float_col4','float_col5']].clip(lower=0).sum()
    #you can pass also mask function
    #x.loc[-1] = x[['float_col4','float_col5']].mask(lambda x: x < 0, 0).sum()
    return x

df = df.groupby('int_col_1').apply(f).reset_index(drop=True).fillna({'int_col_1':'Total'})
print (df)
  int_col_1  int_col2 str_col3  float_col4  float_col5
0       123     456.0   potato         0.1        -0.2
1     Total       NaN      NaN         0.1         0.0
2       456     456.0   potato         0.1         5.0
3       456     456.0   potato         0.1        -0.2
4     Total       NaN      NaN         0.2         5.0
```

Comment: It is elegant solution, +1

Comment: Hey @jezrael , when I run this it returns only the last 2 columns as a dataframe( `float_col4` and `float_col5`) instead of the whole df like the one you showed in your answer. Where are the other ones cut off? I printed `x` before returning it and for the above example it returns something like `(123, 456)    0.1    -0.2` and then `-1    0.1     0.0`. It seems like the lines that are getting cut off are used as an index? and are getting tuppled?

Comment: @Lev - What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: `RangeIndex: 495 entries, 0 to 494
Data columns (total 2 columns):
float_col4           495 non-null float64
float_col5           495 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 7.9 KB
None
`

Comment: @Lev - I think input data ;)

Comment: Oh lol, I actually gave you the info of the produced df, but that was the case for the input data as well since I was grouping by before too xd. Thanks!